# Как с помощью reduce преобразовать массив в объект?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Имеем массив [false, 2 'hello']
Надо с помощью reduce преобразовать в объект с полями {p1: false, p2: 2, p3: 'hello'}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разница с ответом @WVFFLIFE - не создаем на каждой итерации новый объект. Должно работать быстрее.

```js
const arr = [false, 2, 'hello'];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
  acc[`p${index + 1}`] = current;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Небольшой бенчмарк по производительности.

```js
const arr = new Array(1000).fill(2);

console.time('Do not create');

const res = arr.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
  acc[`p${index + 1}`] = current;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.timeEnd('Do not create');


console.time('Create');
const res1 = arr.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
  const key = `p${index + 1}`;
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: current
  }
}, {});
console.timeEnd('Create');
```

Comment: А как работает `console.timeEnd` ?Можно комменты к коду?

Comment: @Demon__ это лучше в документации почитать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ 

Comment: @Demon__ https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd

Comment: @Demon__ `console.time` - "засекает" время. `console.timeEnd` - говорит, сколько времени прошло с момента засекания :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо :)

Answer (score 4):

```js
const arr = [false, 2, 'hello'];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
  const key = `p${index + 1}`;
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: current
  }
}, {});

console.log(res)
```